# Why my Service unit test using mockito and model mapper is not failing?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I am quite new to Spring and Mockito and I am trapped in one tutorial.
I have a simple service which is fetching books from repository

```
@Service
public class BookService {

    private  BookRepository bookRepository;
    private  ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public BookService(BookRepository bookRepository, ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }

    public List<BookDto> fetchAllBooks() {
        List<Book> books = bookRepository.findAll();
        return books.stream()
            .map(convertBookModelToBookDto())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private Function<Book, BookDto> convertBookModelToBookDto() {
        return book -> modelMapper.map(book, BookDto.class);
    }
}
```

Then I have a simple unit test for that service, with just one test

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class BookServiceTest {

@InjectMocks
private BookService bookService;

@Mock
private BookRepository bookRepository;

@Mock
private ModelMapper mapper;

private List<Book> books;
private List<BookDto> bookDtos;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    Book book = getBook("Lord of the Rings", "J.R.R. Tolkien", 1951, "Trilogy");
    Book book2 = getBook("Dune", "Frank Herbert", 1960, "Part I");
    Book book3 = getBook("Hobbit", "J.R.R. Tolkien", 1947, "Story");
    books = new ArrayList<>();
    books.add(book);
    books.add(book2);
    books.add(book3);
    
    BookDto bookDto = getBookDto("Lord of the Rings", "J.R.R. Tolkien", 1951, "Trilogy");
    BookDto bookDto2 = getBookDto("Dune", "Frank Herbert", 1960, "Part I");
    BookDto bookDto3 = getBookDto("Hobbit", "J.R.R. Tolkien", 1947, "Story");
    bookDtos = new ArrayList<>();
    bookDtos.add(bookDto);
    bookDtos.add(bookDto2);
    bookDtos.add(bookDto3);
    
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
}

/**
 * Test of fetchAllBooks method, of class BookService.
 */
@Test
public void testFetchAllBooks() {
    Book book = books.get(0);
    // Mockito.doReturn(bookDtos.get(2)).when(mapper).map(book, BookDto.class);
    // Mockito.doReturn(books).when(bookRepository).findAll();
    Mockito.when(bookRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(books);
    Mockito.when(mapper.map(book, BookDto.class))
        .thenReturn(bookDtos.get(0), bookDtos.get(1), bookDtos.get(2));
    List<BookDto> fetchedBooks = bookService.fetchAllBooks();
    assertThat(fetchedBooks.size()).isEqualTo(3);
    assertThat(fetchedBooks.get(0))
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("title", "Lord of the Rings")
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("author", "J.R.R. Tolkien")
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("releaseYear", 1951)
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("description", "Trilogy");
    assertThat(fetchedBooks.get(1))
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("title", "Dune")
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("author", "Frank Herbert")
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("releaseYear", 1960)
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("description", "Part I");
    assertThat(fetchedBooks.get(2))
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("title", "Hobbit")
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("author", "J.R.R. Tolkien")
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("releaseYear", 1947)
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("description", "Story");
}

private Book getBook(String title, String author, int year, String description) {
    return Book.builder()
            .author(author)
            .title(title)
            .releaseYear(year)
            .description(description)
            .build();
}

private BookDto getBookDto(String title, String author, int year, String description) {
    return BookDto.builder()
            .author(author)
            .title(title)
            .releaseYear(year)
            .description(description)
            .build();
}
}
```

This is my configuration for model mapper

```
@Configuration
public class ModelMapperConfiguration {

@Bean
public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    return new ModelMapper();
}
}
```

This is my Book entity class

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(columnDefinition = "NUMERIC(19,0)")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "title", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String title;

@Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
private String description;

@Column(name = "author", nullable = false)
private String author;

@Column(name = "release_year", nullable = false)
private Integer releaseYear;
}
```

This is my BookDto class

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BookDto {

private Long id;

private String title;

private String description;

private String author;

private Integer releaseYear;
}
```

I dont know why my unit test is not failing, as it should because of this line

```
Mockito.doReturn(bookDtos.get(2)).when(mapper).map(book, BookDto.class);
```

because it should return the third book dto, for each of the fetched books, so the assertions regarding the first and second fetched books should fail...

I dont know what I am missing here.

Spring Boot 2.7.12
Mockito 5.3.1
Assertj 3.24.2
Model Mapper 3.1.1
JUnit 5
Java 17

**Edit 1**

In the assertions of books fetched I was using books, not fetchedBooks.

But now get following error when run test:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expecting actual not to be null
```

at this line:

```
.hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("title", "Dune")
```

Comment: You don't assert anything on the fetched books, only the size of the collection. All your other asserts are on your created list of Books not BookDtos.

Comment: Which is what you wanted... You will get a list with 3 elements, 1 book and 2 `null` elements. Hence your assertions will fail.

Comment: in the code you posted, I only see `Mockito.doReturn(bookDtos.get(2)...` as a comment. What you have really configured is `Mockito.when(mapper.map(book, BookDto.class)).thenReturn(bookDtos.get(0), bookDtos.get(1), bookDtos.get(2));`

Comment: Thanks guys, could you please tell if there is better way, to not have to write the same when statement 3 times ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for comments, indeeed the problem was with my misunderstanding of mockito.

Here is the fixed test which is now working as I expected.

```
@Test
public void testFetchAllBooks() {
    Mockito.doReturn(bookDtos.get(0))
            .when(mapper).map(books.get(0), BookDto.class);
    Mockito.doReturn(bookDtos.get(1))
            .when(mapper).map(books.get(1), BookDto.class);
    Mockito.doReturn(bookDtos.get(2))
            .when(mapper).map(books.get(2), BookDto.class);
    Mockito.doReturn(books)
            .when(bookRepository).findAll();
    List<BookDto> fetchedBooks = bookService.fetchAllBooks();
    assertThat(fetchedBooks.size()).isEqualTo(3);
    assertThat(fetchedBooks.get(0))
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("title", "Lord of the Rings")
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("author", "J.R.R. Tolkien")
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("releaseYear", 1951)
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("description", "Trilogy");
    assertThat(fetchedBooks.get(1))
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("title", "Dune")
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("author", "Frank Herbert")
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("releaseYear", 1960)
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("description", "Part I");
    assertThat(fetchedBooks.get(2))
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("title", "Hobbit")
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("author", "J.R.R. Tolkien")
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("releaseYear", 1947)
        .hasFieldOrPropertyWithValue("description", "Story");
}
```